# Why do you need an extra \r\n in this webserver example?

Tags: sockets

So I'm going through this book called Hacking: The Art of Exploitation, and I'm working with its Tinyweb Server example.

The code snippet goes like this:

```
fd = open(resource, O_RDONLY, 0); //Try to open file
printf("\tOpening \'%s\'\t",resource);
if(fd==-1){ //File not found
    printf(" 404 Not found:\n");
    send_string(sockfd, "HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND\r\n");
    send_string(sockfd, "Server: Tiny webserver\r\n\r\n");
    send_string(sockfd, "<html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>");
    send_string(sockfd, "<body><h1>URL not found</h1></body></html>\r\n");
} else { //Otherwise, serve up the file 
...
```

So, why do you need the extra \r\n in the second send_string call? Without it (say you uncomment that whole line), the browser would just try to load infinitely.

I've also noticed that if you uncomment the first two send_string calls, the page loads just fine. Can you please comment about this too?

Comment: Precisely, refer to section 4.2 of [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of an HTTP response is:

1. Response headers
2. Blank line
3. Response body

You need the blank line to tell where the headers end and the body begins.

Answer (score 1):

You need two `\r\n`'s to tell browser that there is no headers more. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields